# Slashable offences within two eras, what does this mean?

Tags: era, slashing

So reading the [validators docs](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-chill#involuntary-chills):

> If a validator was unresponsive or found to have committed a slashable offense within two era, the `validator` will be removed from the active set in a process known as involuntary chilling.

It is unclear to myself if 'within two era means consecutive. What greater time frame must I avoid offences for to get a clean rap sheet?

Comment: Can you share the link and quote from the reference documentation?

Comment: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/maintain-guides-how-to-chill#involuntary-chills

Comment: If a validator gets added right at the end of a session there would be a danger it could influence the VRF of the next session, so the VRF works off not the last session but the one before. That might explain why a validator could be slashable for two sessions in the past.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Babe pallet of Substrate, there are tests that show that a validator will be removed from the active validator set over the course of two **consecutive** eras.

In the first era, a validator commits an offence and an equivocation proof is reported.
In the second era, the offending validator gets slashed with the unapplied slash from the previous era.
It shows in the the Staking pallet of Substrate, but not in any test, that the offending validator would be involuntarily chilled in the second era, since the effects of removing it from the active validator set in the first era do not take effect until the second era.

The test function where this happens is called `report_equivocation_current_session_works` in the Babe pallet [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/babe/src/tests.rs#L425).

The test function gives each validator in the session the same balance of `10_000_000`, and an exposed slashable balance of `10_000`, and then simulates a case where one of the validators (at index 1) commits an offence and needs enough time to generate an equivocation proof that contains two block header hashes from the current slot within the same first era, and also reports the equivocation proof within that same first era.

The test function then starts a second era so *"the results of the offence report are applied at era end"*, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/babe/src/tests.rs#L473) and checks that 100% of the slashable balance of the offending validator gets slashed to `0` and it checks that they are still staking in that second era but with an exposed slashable balance of `0`.

I think the test could be improved by checking that they are no longer in the active validator set to demonstrate that they have been involuntarily chilled in the second era.

In the Staking pallet implementation where most of this functionality occurs, the `compute_slash` function [here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/slashing.rs#L227) computes the slash of the validator and nominators. It then calls `fetch_spans` to initialize `SlashingSpans` if necessary with a slashing span index, an `AccountId`, and it uses the current era index as the start of the slashing span. It then calls `chill_stash` to involuntarily chill that validator's stash account, which involves removing it from the active validator set, with effects felt at the beginning of the next era (the second era in the case of the above test).

Also in `compute_slash` function, if the slash amount is more than `0`, and the slashable balance of the validator from the most recent slashing span is also more than `0`, and the misbehaviour occurred within the current slashing span then it provides the values to be slashed to `UnappliedSlash` for slashing to occur in the next era (the second era in the case of the above test).

Note that in the above test function, an equivocation offence trait from the Babe or Grandpa pallet may be used along with the `report_offence` function from the Offense pallet to provide equivocation offence data in an equivocation report to a `HandleEquivocation` trait in the corresponding pallet, which has utility methods for handling valid equivocation reports.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit of nuance in those docs, which *slashable offense* but not *slashed.* When a slash is actually applied, a validator is forceably chilled.

For example, being offline will only result in a slash if more than 10% of the set is offline in the same session, so it's possible to be offline for one session and not get slashed. Basically, something bad happened and it was probably just a machine being offline for an hour.

But, if the validator is offline for a session in two consecutive eras, there is probably something faulty with the setup that should be addressed. The network chills the validator to prevent a slash from taking place.

Note: The docs actually mention two consecutive *spans*, and I'm not sure if span equals *era*.

More info here: https://research.web3.foundation/en/latest/polkadot/slashing/npos.html

And the code on this is: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/staking/src/slashing.rs